# скроллинг в DevExpress.XtraGrid

Tags: c#, devexpress

Помогите разобраться со скроллингом в DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl (версия 13.2 компонент). Мне необходимо, чтобы работал горизонтальный скроллинг, а сейчас по факту, когда делаю колонки шире, скроллинг не работает. Хотя у меня выставлено GridView.HorzScrollVisibility = Always; GridView.HorzDcrollStep = 1;GridView.ScrollStyle = LiveHorzScroll; GridView.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = False;
Элементарная вещь, а не работает как надо.

Comment: Поиском умею пользоваться. :-) У меня же написано, что ColumnAutoWidth = False. А у него как раз было ColumnAutoWidth = true (ColumnAutoWidth option checked): The cause of the problem is the ColumnAutoWidth option checked in the grid view's OptionsView property. When it is active, the grid view does not display the horizontal scrollbar, because it adjusts its column widths so that they fit the client area.

Comment: ага, эт я поторопился... добавьте к вопросу минимально достаточный участок вашего кода для воспроизведения проблемы, так сходу не угадывается в чём загвоздка.

Comment: Там все стандартно практически - заданы параметры в компоненте, грид поначалу не виден, потом ему пристаивается датасет и он становится видным.Это можете свое подставить, а свойства по-умолчанию:
            this.gridControl.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.gridControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 88);

Comment: this.gridControl.MainView = this.gridView;
this.gridControl.Name = "gridControl";
this.gridControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1225, 452);
this.gridControl.TabIndex = 4;
this.gridControl.ViewCollection.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView[] {
this.gridView});
this.gridControl.Visible = false;

Comment: this.gridView.Appearance.HeaderPanel.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
this.gridView.Appearance.HeaderPanel.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
this.gridView.Appearance.HeaderPanel.TextOptions.VAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.VertAlignment.Center;
this.gridView.Appearance.HeaderPanel.TextOptions.WordWrap = DevExpress.Utils.WordWrap.Wrap;
this.gridView.Appearance.ViewCaption.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
this.gridView.Appearance.ViewCaption.TextOptions.WordWrap = DevExpress.Utils.WordWrap.Wrap;

Comment: this.gridView.AppearancePrint.HeaderPanel.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
this.gridView.AppearancePrint.HeaderPanel.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
this.gridView.AppearancePrint.HeaderPanel.TextOptions.VAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.VertAlignment.Center;
this.gridView.AppearancePrint.HeaderPanel.TextOptions.WordWrap = DevExpress.Utils.WordWrap.Wrap;
this.gridView.GridControl = this.gridControl;
this.gridView.HorzScrollStep = 1;
this.gridView.HorzScrollVisibility = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ScrollVisibility.Always;
this.gridView.Name = "gridView";

Comment: this.gridView.OptionsBehavior.AllowAddRows = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.gridView.OptionsBehavior.AllowDeleteRows = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.gridView.OptionsBehavior.Editable = false;
this.gridView.OptionsBehavior.ReadOnly = true;
this.gridView.OptionsCustomization.AllowRowSizing = true;
this.gridView.OptionsLayout.Columns.StoreAppearance = true;
this.gridView.OptionsLayout.StoreAppearance = true;
this.gridView.OptionsPrint.AutoWidth = false;
this.gridView.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;
this.gridView.OptionsView.RowAutoHeight = true;

Comment: Код должен быть в вопросе ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/826305/edit)).